# How to detect top edge of QR code in Python and pyzbar

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I'm using pyzbar + opencv to detect QR code. I need to draw somethings on the top edge of QR code for printing purpose. I know pyzbar can detect the bounding box of QR code but it's hard to know which edge is top.

Any suggestion?

Need to detect top edge like these examples:
[image: Need to detect top edge like these examples]

Answer (score 0):

If the top edge always start and end with regtangle in the edges you can try detect with `cv2.contour` where the two rectangle in the image and than use `cv2.line` to draw line vetween the two edges

[Use this great tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) to detect the square in the edges and then get the start x,y points of each

**I hope I help you if you get stucked please tell me and I try help you**

Answer (score 0):

> If you want your QR picture to get identified, rotated and scaled correctly you need the following task :

(you needs the combination of two techniques)

- First step: detect the x,y coordinates of the 4 corners of each QR code. The Python library zbar is useful for this :

`print(symbol.location)` gives the coordinates.

- Second step: now a deskewing / perspective correction / "homography" is needed. Here is how to do it with Python + OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but maybe it will help someone in the future:

- **PyZbar** detects QR codes well (gives almost perfect position of QRcode corners) but you don't get information where is top of the QRcode
- **OpenCV** in my test was not as good but it return a list of corner points [top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left]. It is not documented behavior but it always works like this.

*[tested with opencv-python==4.5.5.62]*

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **pyzbar** to do this.

Use `decoded.polygon`. It will return the polygon of the QR code.

In this example, we are using this image as input:

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from pyzbar import pyzbar

# Open image with PIL
img_input = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')

# Create a draw object
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_input)
```

Now we will use pyzbar to decode the image into QR Code, if any.

And then, we'll use `decoded.polygon` to get edges coordinates of the QR code and use **PIL** to draw the edges and diagonal line of the QR code:

```
# Decode the image into QR code, if any
decoder = pyzbar.decode(img_input)

if len(decoder) != 0:
    for decoded in decoder:
        if decoded.type == 'QRCODE':
            # Draw only top edge of polygon with PIL
            draw.line(decoded.polygon[2:4], fill = '#0F16F1', width = 5)
            
            # Draw only buttom edge of polygon with PIL
            draw.line(decoded.polygon[0:2], fill = '#D40FF1', width = 5)

            # Draw only left edge of polygon with PIL
            draw.line(decoded.polygon[0:4:3], fill = '#FD7A24', width = 5)

            # Draw only right edge of polygon with PIL
            draw.line(decoded.polygon[1:3], fill = '#00D4F1', width = 5)

            # Draw diagonal line of polygon with PIL
            draw.line(decoded.polygon[1:4:2], fill = '#00D354', width = 5)
```

Now we can simply save the result image with the following command:

```
img_input.save('image_and_polygon.png')
```

And the output will be:

[image]

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!